# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start for .pdf file paths in SQL

Tags: c#, file

Good day.
In my C# windows forms app, I would like to open .pdf files.
The code to do this is:

```
private void btnOpenPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(lblPdf.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The .pdf file paths are storred in an SQL database. 
They are stored in this manner: C:\Folder1\Folder2\File Name

In this example this means:

```
lblPdf.Text="C:\Folder1\Folder2\File Name";
```

*note: File Name(s) is/are stored without file type (so no .pdf at the end)

Of course this doesn't work, so I added the "@" and ".pdf" to the string:

```
lblTest.Text = ("@" + "\"" + lblPdf.Text + ".pdf" + "\"");
```

When I test this with a Message Box:

```
MessageBox.Show(lblTest);
```

I get:

```
 @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\File Name.pdf"
```

The trouble I am experiencing is that this works:

```
private void btnOpenPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lblTest.Text);            
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Folder1\Folder2\File Name.pdf");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and this does not work:

```
private void btnOpenPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lblTest.Text);            
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(lblTest.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed a light on why this is so?

The error message I receive in the second example is:
"The system cannot find the file specified"

MessageBox.Show gives me the correct syntax and file path in both cases.

Thank you.

Comment: When setting the Label.Text you don't need to use the @ verbatim character. As you do it now the @ becomes part of the string passed to the Start method, in the constant example is instead used by the compiler to correctly interpret the \ as path separators  and not as the introduction of an escape sequence

Comment: Can you confirm  that your message box shows this exact text ' @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\File Name.pdf"'  ? If that is true, as in that is exactly what is printed, then there is your issue

Comment: can we see the code where lblTest.Text gets set?

Comment: `"@" + ` - what? `@` in front of string literal at compile time is not same as prepending string with `"@"` at run-time.

Comment: @Dave, yes that is exactly what is printed

Answer (score 0):

@Shovers and anyone else to whom it may concern:

```
        private void btnOpenPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        lblTest.Text = ("@" +lblPdf.Text + ".pdf" );
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lblTest.Text);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(lblTest.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `"@" + "\"" +` before and `+ "\""` after the string, so only add `".pdf"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

Just adding the

```
 + ".pdf"
```

to the label (`lblPdf.Text`) is the answer.

```
private void btnOpenPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(lblPdf.Text + ".pdf");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I can give you a number of hints:

**1 Exceptions**

Proper exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and yours is problematic. Your code handles fatal exceptions. And never catching fatal exceptions is a very important part. Doing it will only get you more and less understandable followup errors. Here are two artciles on the mater I do link often:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

**2. How are those PDF stores with the Database?**

PDFs are Binary Large Objects (BLOBS). Ther are two schools of tought on to store blobs with a DB and both affect wich path you have to give:

- You store the blob itself in the DB. Usually that requires setting up a HTTP handler to provide the file for download/user consumption. In this case you need a URL to access those files
- You store the files in the Filesystem. The DB only contains the paths. In this case you have to eitehr use the URL, Share path or whatever else way you got to download those files
- [SQL Filestream](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) and equivalent attributes from other DB are a bit of a combination of the two. It works mostly like the 1st one, with performance closer to the 2nd one.
- You might have some 4th bastardised version here. Or you simply did not understand how how to use the values in the DB.

Comment: The PDFs are stored on a server (disk). The database contains only file locations and file names.

Comment: @Parus: The files must either be avalible via a HTTP server or a network share. Or by your programm running on the DB/File Server. Otherwise the average windows programm has 0 chance of accessing them. You need to break it down to a URI/URL to have any chance of leaving it to default PDF viewer.